# Kafka installation : Nota ble to start kafka server in windows environment

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

I have installed the `kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0` version of Kafka in windows 10 environment.
I am trying to start kafka-server using below command in `bash` shell but getting below error :

```
XXXX@XX-00000XXX /c/Software/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/bin
λ ./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties
/c/Software/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 177: C:\Program: No such file or directory
XXXX@XX-00000XXX /c/Software/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/bin
```

Please let me know how I can fix this.

Comment: Windows is not officially supported. Please download direct from Kafka website.

Answer (score 0):

You have something in your PATH that contains spaces

For example, `Program Files\Java`

This is a long outstanding issue in the windows start scripts can can be solved by running all necessary software without spaces in the paths